# How to apply SELECT date('now') query in android?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-cursor, android-database

I am working on a project and now I have been stuck on a weird stage.

I know that we can execute any query that has to do anything with database we can write that using:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM table_name", null);
```

But now I want to execute this query:

```
"SELECT strftime('%s','now','-2 day')"
```

Generally the above query returns **unixepoch time of one day before yesterday**.

Does anyone know how can I get this done?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the query. I just want to know how to apply this kind of query. Because when I apply using the above method it searches for the column name strftime('%s','now','-2 day').

You know what I am saying?

Comment: So why not just use it? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I want to get epoch time of the day before yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would handle this query like any other query:

```java
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime('%s','now','-2 day')", null);
try {
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        long seconds = cursor.getLong(0);
        ...
    } else {
        // cannot happen with this query
    }
} finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

If you want to access the column by name (which is completely pointless if you have only a single column), you can give it an alias:

```java
cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT strftime(...) AS s", null);
cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow("s");  // returns zero
...
```

---

Please note that for queries that return a single value, there is a [helper function](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#longForQuery%28android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29):

```java
long seconds = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(
                   db, "SELECT strftime('%s','now','-2 day')", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date = new Date();
```

will return the current day, if you then subtract X numbers of days, then parse that Date to String with the required format. You can do this with the method `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
String newDate = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern).format(date);
```

where pattern can be something like this `"dd-MM-yyyy"`

Then, you can add said date to your query.

Comment: Since we can execute any SQLite query, I am just curious about this query, How can I execute these types of queries that doesn't have to do with database? You can check this link https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html